# Subtract elements from 2 arrays found in 2 different .csv files

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have two csv files with 1 row of data each and multiple columns

```
csv1: 0.1924321564, 0.8937481241, 0.6080270062, ........

csv2: 0.1800000000, 0.7397439374, 0.3949274792, ........
```

I want to subtract the first value in csv1 from the first value in csv2:

```
e.g 0.1924321564 - 0.1800000000 = 0.0124321564
    0.8937481241 - 0.7397439374 = 0.15400418706
```

and continue this for the remaining columns.

I then want to take the results of the subtraction of each column and sum them together into one value e.g `sum(0.0124321564 + 0.15400418706 + n)`

I am very new to python so this is the code I started with:

```
import numpy as np
import csv


array1 = np.array('1.csv')
array2 = np.array('2.csv')

array3 = np.subtract(array1, array2)
total = np.sum(array3)
```

Comment: A CSV file shouldn't normally have a space after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

## [`genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

*note:* the `delimeter` is comma followed by a space because that is what you showed.  Please change accordingly.

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.genfromtxt('1.csv', delimiter=', ')
array2 = np.genfromtxt('2.csv', delimiter=', ')

(array1 - array2).sum()

0.37953587010000012
```